# Difference between `/dev/ttyS0` and `/dev/ttys0`?

Tags: linux, serial-port

In Linux, what is the difference between `/dev/ttyS0` and `/dev/ttys0`?

I know that the first is a serial port, but what about the second, with the small `s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see this](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-6.html)

> For a pseudo terminal pair such as
>   ptyp3 and ttyp3, the pty... is the
>   master or controlling terminal and the
>   tty... is the slave. There are only 16
>   ttyp's: ttyp0-ttypf (f is a
>   hexadecimal digit). **To get more
>   pairs, the 3 letters q, r, s may be
>   used instead of p**. For example the
>   pair ttys8, ptys8 is a pseudo terminal
>   pair. The master and slave are really
>   the same "port" but the slave is used
>   by the application program and the
>   master is used by a network program
>   (or the like) which supplies (and
>   gets) data to/from the slave port.

Answer (score 0):

And this: http://lists.opensuse.org/archive/opensuse/2003-12/msg02404.html

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux devices.txt file in the kernel docs it says:

```
3 char    Pseudo-TTY slaves
      0 = /dev/ttyp0    First PTY slave
      1 = /dev/ttyp1    Second PTY slave
        ...
    255 = /dev/ttyef    256th PTY slave

    These are the old-style (BSD) PTY devices; Unix98
    devices are on major 136 and above.
```

and goes on to say

```
4 char    TTY devices
      0 = /dev/tty0     Current virtual console

      1 = /dev/tty1     First virtual console
        ...
     63 = /dev/tty63    63rd virtual console
     64 = /dev/ttyS0    First UART serial port
        ...
    255 = /dev/ttyS191  192nd UART serial port

    UART serial ports refer to 8250/16450/16550 series devices.

    Older versions of the Linux kernel used this major
    number for BSD PTY devices.  As of Linux 2.1.115, this
    is no longer supported.  Use major numbers 2 and 3.
```

I don't know how much this helps you, but should get you started in the right direction.